# Why is this not an infinite loop?

Tags: javascript

I'm reading this [this example](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/html5/articles/javascript-design-patterns-pt1-singleton-composite-facade.html#articlecontentAdobe_numberedheader_0) and I'm stuck at understanding one line. I need to understand everything so I can't move on.

This function is supposed to hide all the elements inside an object. It's supposed to work. But to me, that for loop looks like an infinite one. Why is it not?

```
getChild: function (i) {
    return this.children[i];
},

hide: function () {
    for (var node, i = 0; node = this.getChild(i); i++) {
        node.hide();
    }

    this.element.hide(0);
},
```

From what I see, the function takes the first element of the object with getChild(0) and then calls hide again on that 0-dimension object. Then it resets the counter (i) and gets the first element of the 0-dimension object (which is the same 0-dim object) and calls the function again.

I know I'm mistaken but that's what I see. Please show me the light! Thanks

Comment: Javascript conditionals work on "falsy" and "truthy" values. If getChild(i) ever returns a null or undefined then the condition is considered false and the for loop halts.

Comment: What is `this.element`? Or do you ask for the for-loop?

Answer (score 7):

In a `for` loop like the one above, the first bit (`var node, i = 0`) is only executed once, at the beginning of the loop.  The loop stops executing when the middle section (`node = this.getChild(i);`) returns false.  `getChild` will return false when there isn't anything at index `i`.  (Technically, it'll return `undefined`, but that equates to `false` in this instance).

Secondly, even though `hide()` is called in the for loop, `i` is not reset.  Why?  This recursive call creates a new instance of `hide()` separate from the original.  All of the variables in this new `hide()` are separate from the original.  (and so on, down the rabbit hole).

See http://www.tizag.com/javascriptT/javascriptfor.php for more information on for loops.

Comment: yes, but after it calls node.hide() again from inside the for loop, doesn't it reset both node and i again?

Comment: This is the only reply that actually addresses what the OP asked (about `i=0`).

Comment: @jsebcortes Nope, that recursive call executes a different instance of that loop.

Comment: @jsebcortes No: everything between `var` and the first `;` is part of the init condition, and executes only once. Note that `node` and `i` are separated by a comma - not a semicolon. People often use it to do stuff like `for(var i=0, len=array.length; i<len; i++)` to avoid repeatedly checking `array.length`.

Comment: Yeah, I know it will start another instance of the loop, calling to hide an object of only one element of size (dimension 0). Then it will call the function again, and getChild of that element. Which is going to return that same element. Then its going to call the node.hide() function once again. It will start infinite instances of for loops, all dealing with objects of 0-dimension. I can't see when does it get out of any of the loops it starts, as there's always going to be a getChild valid return for i=0 in every instance.

Comment: @jsebcortes I was mistaken. There is **no** new instance of the loop made by `node.hide()`. The function call will simply hide the element, end of story. The the loop will run again. And when it does, `i` will be incremented by 1, so it will be `this.getChild(1)`. If there is no element at index 1 in `this.children`, it will return `undefined` which is a falsy value, thus terminating the loop.

Answer (score 2):

The variable `i` is not reset on each iteration. The only actions that are recurisvely executed are the boolean expression and `i++`. `node.hide()` is not the same as `this.hide()`. The latter is a different function being called. If it were the same function, then yes, there would be an infinite loop.

The "outer" hide function is being used to "hide" all the elements in `this.getChild(i)`. `node.hide()` will call the `hide()` method on those elements so they are hidden. There is no infinite loop because `node.hide()`, although it has the same name as the function it's being used in, is **not** the same function.

Comment: i will not be reset on each iteration, but on every instance the function is called again every `node.hide()` it will start a new instance of the for loop with "new" i and var variables, no?

Comment: @jsebcortes No, the for loop is not affected by `node.hide()` or anything inside the loop body. It's that when the function body is run, the loop will start again with the same variables. It's just that every time it iterates, the variable `i` is incremented. It's the same variable, with a different value. That's all. But inside the function call of `hide`, there are different variables created.

Comment: I don't seem to be getting it so I'm going to keep on asking. Thanks for your patience.

Yeah, 
I

Comment: @jsebcortes `node.hide()` is not the function through which it's being called! The function is not being called again. If it was, it'd be called through `this.hide()`. `node.hide()` is **not** the same as `this.hide()`. `node.hide()` is a completely different function.

Comment: @jsebcortes Are you understanding now? The "outer" `hide` function is being used to "hide" all the elements in `this.getChild(i)`. `node.hide()` will call the `hide()` method on those elements so they are hidden. There is no infinite loop because `node.hide()`, although it has the same name as the function it's being used in, is **not** the same function. Do you get it?

Comment: Even if it was the same function being called recursively I don't think it would be an infinite loop or infinite recursion, because each time the for loop starts it sets `node` to a _child_ of `this` so eventually it would reach a leaf node and stop recursing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

1. The code

   `node.hide();`

   is still a member of the tree and still traversable. It is just hidden from being displayed.
2. The initialization part of the for loop

   `var node, i=0`

   is executed only once, before the looping begins.
3. The conditional

   `node = this.getChild(i)`

   evaluates to true (non-null) when there is a child node, and false (null) when it has run out of descendants, thereby breaking out of the loop.

Comment: I understand. But then, before getting out of the first iteration of the for loop, the function calls again a node.hide and starts an "inside" instance of the loop, right? Then it evaluates again getChild(i) for i=0 on this second instance. It will always have a valid return...

Comment: With node.hide(), the node is not deleted. It is still there for code to traverse. It is just hidden from display; the display properties of the node are set to "none."

Answer (score 0):

If there is no child at `i`, `getChild` will return `undefined` and break out of the loop.

Consider the following text from the article:

> Now create the GalleryImage class. Notice that it uses all of the exact same methods as the GalleryComposite. In other words, they implement the same interface, **except that the image is a leaf so it doesn't actually do anything for the methods regarding children, as it cannot have any**. Using the same interface is required for the composite to work because a composite element doesn't know whether it's adding another composite element or a leaf, so if it tries to call these methods on its children, it needs to work without any errors.

And consider the constructor for `GalleryImage`:

```
var GalleryImage = function (src, id) {
  this.children = [];

  this.element = $('<img />')
  .attr('id', id)
  .attr('src', src);
}
```

And how the images and composites are constructed:

```
var container = new GalleryComposite('', 'allgalleries');
var gallery1 = new GalleryComposite('Gallery 1', 'gallery1');
var gallery2 = new GalleryComposite('Gallery 2', 'gallery2');
var image1 = new GalleryImage('image1.jpg', 'img1');
var image2 = new GalleryImage('image2.jpg', 'img2');
var image3 = new GalleryImage('image3.jpg', 'img3');
var image4 = new GalleryImage('image4.jpg', 'img4');

gallery1.add(image1);
gallery1.add(image2);

gallery2.add(image3);
gallery2.add(image4);

container.add(gallery1);
container.add(gallery2);
```

Since an image cannot contain children, its `this.children` will remain an empty array. So, when the `hide` function finally gets called on an image (at one of the leaves of the composite tree), the loop will attempt to evaluate `this.children[0]` which will return `undefined`. This will cause the code `node = this.getChild(i)` to evaluate to a "false" value, and that particular `for` loop will terminate. Thus preventing an endless loop.

Comment: there's always something at getChild(0) for every i=0 in every instance of recurring loop.

Comment: @jsebcortes - Not at the leaf nodes. Please see my updated answer.